# .on load - não funciona JQUERY

Tags: jquery, load

Sério, não consegui entender.

Antigamente sempre usava a função load do jquery assim:

```
$('#db0077').load('/inc/aula.php', function(){
        alert('dentro do load');
    });
```

Agora essa função está obsoleta. Então eu vi que tenho que usar o .on() para isso. Usar o .on() é muito simples, consigo em todas as funções, menos nessa!!! eu tentei assim:

```
$('#db0077').on('load', '/inc/aula.php', function(){
        alert('dentro do load');
    });
```

Não funciona de jeito nenhum, alguém me dá uma luz?

Comment: Ann... quem te falou que o método **load** está obsoleta??

Answer (score 1):

O método `.load()` sempre funcionou como um shorthand de Ajax. Antes do jQuery 1.8 o método funcionava também como evento `load` do JavaScript, ou seja, `$(window).load()` era o mesmo que `window.onload`. A partir da versão 1.8 o método tornou-se obsoleto para esse evento e foi removido a partir da versão 3.0, ficando apenas com a função de Ajax.

O método `.on()` é usado para disparar eventos (click, change, load etc.), só que no caso de `load` é usado com elementos assíncronos: `$(window).on("load"...`, `$("img").on("load"...`, `$("iframe").on("load"...` etc. Não funciona com div porque div não é assíncrono.

Resumindo, continue usando `.load()` para carregar conteúdo na div que não está obsoleto não. O que tornou-se obsoleto, a partir da versão 1.8, foi o uso de `.load()` como evento.